# How to interpret the graph

Tags: python, seaborn

I have data something like this and I had given a task to plot the pairplot graph from this data, I plotted the graph with following columns `mpg, weight, and origin` but  I am not able to interpret the graph so could you help me in understanding that

this is 5 records of the dataset

[image]

and  this is the pairplot I got as output

[image]

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Why not ask the person who has given you the task of plotting the pairplot how to interpret the result?

Comment: @ Diziet Asahi  was that your answer

Comment: Well, to adequately answer your question, a lot of background information is needed. The person who provided the data is the most suited to explain what the data are about. If your question is about what a pairplot means in general, there are [the docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html). Whatever you need, your question doesn't seem to be suited for StackOverflow.